# jQuery Datatables Custom Search Plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, search, filter, datatables

I am a beginner when it comes to Web development. I am converting my C# winforms app into a web app.

I am trying to implement custom search on a table using `jQuery` Datatables Plugin. Considering the custom search example (https://datatables.net/examples/plug-ins/range_filtering.html). I would like to show details of all the employees except whose office is in "Edinburgh".

Filter rest of the employees via `textbox`.

So basically `sql` equivalent of

```
select * from employees where office not like '%Edinburgh%';
```

This would display all the employees and their details except those whose office is in Edinburgh.
I would like to perform filter on these employees.

**EDIT:**

I have compiled a Fiddle (https://jsfiddle.net/53futc2w/5/) using jQuery Datatables and populated with data.

On clicking the Non SC button I would like to display only the values which do not have "*SC*" in their description.

So basically `sql` equivalent of

```
select * from products where description not like '%SC%';
```

These values to be filtered based on the input provided into the textbox

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if 'Edinburgh' should be hard-coded, or if you'd like users to be able to specify a value of their own, so here is the hard-coded solution, with comments for user-provided value option:

```
$.fn.dataTable.ext.search.push(function(settings, data, dataIndex) {
    var exclude = 'Edinburgh'; // User provided value: $("#user-exclude-field").val();

    if(!exclude) return true; // nothing to exclude, so all rows should be included

    var re = new Regexp("\\b" + exclude + "\\b", "i"); // using the \b word boundary meta-character to match only "Edinburgh" and not "NewEdinburgh" (typo on purpose)
    return !re.test(data.office); // return TRUE (i.e. include this row in the search results) if the "office" attribute of the current row data does NOT match our excluded word
});
```

**UPDATE**

So based on your comment, here's a sample fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/bjLzkjnc/

**UPDATE 2**

So you want to instead be able to filter for all items that contain a word, or filter for all rows that do not contain that word. Update fiddle:  jsfiddle.net/1xh3kys5

The magic here is the `filter` variable. Before it was just a boolean variable because we wanted to track two states: "contains SC" vs "show me everything". But now you actually have three states: "contains SC", "show me everything" and "show me everything that does *not* contain SC"... So a boolean is no longer enough.

There are a few ways to approach this, but I went with a filters object, so that you could eventually add more filters easily:

```
var filters = {
    sc: {active: false, re: new RegExp("\\bSC\\b", "i"), include: true}
};
```

The filters object here has only one attribute, one filter, called "sc". That attribute is itself an object, that has a few attributes that will let us represent all of our three states:

- **active** is to turn this particular "sc" filter on/off. So when you want to show all rows, you simply set this to false, and deactivate the sc filter.
- **include** is our boolean to control whether we want to include or exclude rows that contains the word "SC".
- **re** is simply the regular expression we will use when we want to filter the rows.

When we filter rows now, we simply use the regular expression to determine if a particular row contains "SC".

```
var includes_sc = filters.sc.re.test(data[2]);
return (filters.sc.include ? includes_sc : !includes_sc);
```

So, based on the "include" attribute's value, and store it in a variable called `includes_sc`. If the current filter wants all rows that *include* "SC", we return `includes_sc` as is. If, on the other hand, we want all rows that *do not include* "SC", we return the inverse (!includes_sc) of `includes_sc`.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks a million. That did the trick.
I am trying to toggle the same by using Radio Buttons instead of a normal button.

https://jsfiddle.net/bjLzkjnc/1/

Please find the updated fiddle

Comment: Right, so you simply have to set the global `exclude_sc` variable to the value of your choice, and then redraw your table. So in the case of radio buttons, just make sure when they are clicked they set `exclude_sc` and then redraw.

Comment: After setting the global exclude_sc I am able to toggle the radio buttons to obtain the output. I am trying to display only the values which have SC in them. Unfortunately I am not able to do that. https://jsfiddle.net/perfectnoob/bjLzkjnc/2/ I have included the updated fiddle.

Comment: Aha! So you changed the logic a bit - not it's not just a toggle of with SC vs everything, but with SC vs without SC... Here's an updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/1xh3kys5/

Comment: Thank you very much MacPrawn. That did it.
If you could explain a bit, it would be wonderful. I am migrating towards web development. If you could recommend any training for a beginner that would be fantastic.

Comment: Hi @Tango! I've updated my response with more details on what the code is doing. Let me know if you still have questions. As for resources for web development, I do not have one in particular, but you can find many on the web.